# SimpleXML Node Selection

Tags: php, simplexml

I am trying to select a line in an XML using SimpleXML in PHP. I have toe code loading in the XML which looks like this.

```
    <Row>
        <Cell name="ID">S061102000000000000000006492017092915:13</Cell>
    </Row>
```

I have got my code to select the name however want it to select the value for that name. At the moment my line in PHP looks like this

```
    <?php
       $xml=simplexml_load_file("test.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create 
       object");

       echo "'".$xml->book[0]->title['name'] . "',<br>";
     ?>
```

So this obviously outputs the text

> ID

I however want the value for this row. Just so you are also aware there are more  Cell Name values where I want to get the content from such as

```
<Cell name="Name">First Name</Cell>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your xml format, the code should look something like this

```
$xml = '<Row>
    <Cell name="ID">S061102000000000000000006492017092915:13</Cell>
</Row>';

$data = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
echo "Name:" . $data->Cell["name"] . "\n";
echo "Value:" . (string)$data->Cell . "\n";
```

or if your have to handle multiple cell tags, loop over the data

```
$xml = '<Row>
    <Cell name="ID">S061102000000000000000006492017092915:13</Cell>
    <Cell name="Name">Value</Cell>
</Row>';

$data = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
foreach ($data as $cell) {
    echo "Name:" . $cell["name"] . "\n";
    echo "Value:" . (string)$cell . "\n";
}
```

Comment: `echo`ing casts to string implicitly so the cast operator is not necessary.

Comment: the echo is just an example - normaly you would use the value somewhere else - i.e. for substr or kind of stuff. If you forget the cast in this cases, you get some errors/warnings for object to string conversion. So I wrote it implicitly

Answer (score 0):

Why do you get attribute `name` if you want to get body of the tag?

Instead of

```
$xml->book[0]->title['name']
```

You should use

```
$xml->book[0]->title
```

In your case it should be

```
$xml->Row[0]->Cell
```

You may learn more about geting node/attribute values [here](https://www.w3schools.com/PhP/php_xml_simplexml_get.asp).